# Проблема с циклом

Tags: c, циклы

Проблема в том что мой цикл `for (min; (min < (min+dx));min+=dx2)` бесконечный( не могу понять что не так с условием?

```
int main(void)
{
    float dx = 1, fx, x, min = 100000, dx2 = 0.5;
    x = x1;

    while ((x >= x1) && (x <= x2))
    {
        fx = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;

        if (fx < min)
        {
            min = fx;
        }

        x += dx;
    }

    printf(" min %f \n ", min);

    for (min; (min < (min + dx)); min += dx2)
    {
        printf(" min %f \n ", min);
    }

    printf(" min %f \n ", min);
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `(min < (min+dx)` простите, а когда это правда?

Comment: по идее т,к min=3 то min+dx=4 получается min++dx покуда не дойдёт до 4 или не так?

Comment: подозреваю должно быть `for(float i=min; i < min + dx; i+=dx2)`

Comment: спасибо уже разобрался)

Answer (score 5):

Издеваетесь? :)

```
for (min; (min < (min+dx));min+=dx2)
```

Это условие - `min < (min+dx)` - будет справедливо, как бы это выразиться... почти всегда. Пока прибавление `dx` не перестанет влиять на значение `min`. Так что цикл не то чтобы бесконечный, но - близок к этому :)

Что вы вообще хотите посчитать?

Кстати, как вы его вообще скомпилировали? Неизвестные переменные `x1`, `x2`, `a`, `b`, `c`...

Comment: эти переменные заданы как константы у меня

Comment: а как написать это условие что бы было правильно?

Comment: А что вы хотите? Поясните, что вам нужно - и тогда будет понятно, как и что написать...

Comment: мне надо цикл с условием 3<4 3 это min 4 я представил в виде min+dx (dxв моем случае 1) как изменить что бы не писать 4 т,к я не знаю что пред минимумом 4 идет а не другое число

Comment: Условие 3<4 всегда  истинно; цикл с таким условием будет выполняться бесконечно.

Comment: ааааа все понял как сделать)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `min` всегда (ну, [почти всегда](http://ideone.com/hfPsHh)) меньше, чем `min+dx`.

Comment: Что это за почти? Переполнение?

Comment: @vp_arth, там float, так что не совсем переполнение. http://ideone.com/hfPsHh

Comment: Предел точности съедает единичку) Ясно, спасибо.